# Automatically import libraries into multiple Scala files

Tags: scala

I'm writing a lot of scripts that use the same import statements, and I was thinking of collecting all the import statements into one file, and importing that file.  However, apparently imports in Scala are not recursive, so I can't do that.  Is there another way I can consolidate my import statements?

Comment: good question.  I'd like to know as well.

Comment: If you mean script, you can `scala -nc -i header.scala headerscript.scala`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can:

```
package blah

object Imports {
  type Class1 = some.package.Class1
  // companion object
  val Class1 = some.package.Class1
  type Trait2[A] = some.other.package.Trait2[A]
  // etc.
}
```

and then in other files

```
import blah.Imports._
```

You can also use a package object:

```
package object blah {
  // same contents as Imports had above
}
```

and

```
import blah._ // automatically imported inside package blah or subpackages
```